# Deactivate the clear button in input fields for IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having trouble with a form in IE8. The input fields show the clear button like in the image below:

[image: Input field clear button IE8]

The solution I found in the web is to introduce this in my css:

```
.someinput::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work in IE8.

I would like to make this button disappear because IE8 doesn't handle well the `change` event either to check when the field is cleared. (In IE8 the `click` event can be used, but when the handler is called the value is still not cleared)

Does anybody know how to solve this issue in IE8? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using actual IE8 or an emulated version through IE10/IE11? The clear button doesn't show in IE8

Comment: Actually I'm using the emulated version. Sorry I didn't mention it. I was naive expecting it to be the same...

Comment: Thanks Wickywills for your help. I have written an answer based in your comment after verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue only happens when using the emulator in latest version of Internet Explorer.

In IE8 there are no clear buttons in form inputs.